# C# Entity Framework adding one to many relationship entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

In my `DbContext` class, I have 2 tables that have a one-to-many relationship.

Firstly I create one `Location` object, then I try to add a `ParkingSpot` object that references to the `Location` object, but in a database, it is not adding the `ParkingSpot` object to the database. What do I do wrong?

`DbContext` class:

```
public class ParkingDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ParkingDBContext() : base("DbConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParkingSpot> ParkingSpots { get; set; }
}
```

`Location` class:

```
public class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        ParkingSpots = new List<ParkingSpot>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ParkingSpot> ParkingSpots { get; set; }
}
```

`ParkingSpot` class:

```
public class ParkingSpot
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

The way that I'm trying to add new `ParkingSpot`:*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string Id,string locationId)
{
    try
    {
        Location loc = dbContext.Locations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == locationId);
        dbContext.ParkingSpots.Add(new ParkingSpot { Id = Id, Location = loc });
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your EF mapping code looks like?

Comment: How do you check for new `ParkingSpot`s? Are you sure you check the right database? Checking the wrong database is a very common error, esp. when using localdb.

Comment: I’ve created a sample project and seems like everything is working for me. Are you sure that parameters `Id` and `locationId` are correct and that location is being received from the database by that `locationId`? Also after you call `SaveChanges()` can you press on the `dbContext.ParkingSpots` and see if the new `ParkingSpot` appeared there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no column in `ParkingSpot` to hold the ID of the `Location` to which it relates. Try adding the following to `ParkingSpot`:

```
public string LocationId {get; set;}
```

Without it you won't be able to set up the mapping properly...

Comment: I only spotted that after I'd posted the answer: looks like the change to the tag that occurred an hour ago made it appear in my SO home page. When I saw the date I certainly didn't expect it to be accepted so thanks!